# Wordpress acf custom field date - hide expired events

Tags: wordpress, datepicker, advanced-custom-fields

This question has been asked loads and have tried the various different ways but can't seem to make this work!

I have a custom post type 'events' with a custom field 'date' done through acf.

I can list all events with date and order them by date. But I want to hide dates that are past the current date. The code I have is:

```
<?php

  query_posts( array( 
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'meta_key'          => 'date',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'ASC'
     ) );
  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>

<div class="event-block">
  <div class="event-block-info">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <p><?php
      $endDateText = date_i18n("d M Y", strtotime(get_field('date')));
      echo $endDateText;
  ?></p>
  <div class="event-block-image">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' ); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>


<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to compare the end event date you get from acf field with the actual time and avoid to print out past events .

...

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

 if(strtotime(get_field('date'))<time()){
     continue;
  }
?>
 <div class="event-block">
```

....

Comment: This has worked for the main event page which lists all events. However on my home page I want to just pull through just the event coming up. I thought I could just replicate this and add a 'posts_per_page => 1' by it seems to be taking into account the hidden events and so nothing displays.

Any ideas based on whats been done, how to just show the 1 upcoming event?

Comment: you could query all  posts with  meta_key 'date' greater than today and ordering the results in incrising  order by 'date'. Than get the first element of the resulting array

Comment: Thanks.

I've tried a couple of goes at it, trying different code and can't seem to get it working.

How would the code look?